# Symfony forms вывести список элементов с fileType

Tags: form, symfony

Может кто-то что подскажет, у меня есть список критериев у них в entity есть флаг docRequired, я хочу выводить их и если флаг true показывать инпут с filetype.

Вообще вся суть что есть RegistrationRequest , и часть этого CriteriaRequest которая имеет PriorityRequest, ниже попробую вставить код что я пытаюсь делать.

```
class PriorityCriteria
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var EducationLevel[]|ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\EducationLevel")
     */
    private $educationLevels;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="text", type="text")
     */
    private $text;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="doc_required", type="boolean")
     */
    private $docRequired = false;




 class CriteriaRequest
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Many User have Many Phonenumbers.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PriorityCriteria")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="criteria_criteriarequest",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="criteria_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="criteriarequest_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     */
    private $priorityCriteria;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RegistrationRequest", inversedBy="criteriaRequest")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="registration_request_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $registrationRequest;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="doc", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $doc;
```

Пробовал получить сразу список критериев и вставить их в formType и через choice function вывести тогда в темплайте кое как получается вывести по переменным. Но тогда не знаю как это потом всё сохранить... И другой вариант в FormType передать пустой обьект CriteriaRequest и через queryBuilder внутри получить критерии но тогда просто критерии сформировать я могу а input Doc type нет

```
    public function criteriaRequestListAction(Request $request, $educationLevel)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

//        $criteria = $em->getRepository('RegistrationBundle:PriorityCriteria')->getCriteriaList($educationLevel);
        $criteria = new CriteriaRequest();
        $form = $this->createForm(CriteriaRequestType::class, $criteria);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
//        dump($form);die;
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            dump($criteria);die;
            $em->persist($criteria);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('criteria_index');
        }
```

сама форма...

```
    class CriteriaRequestType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('priorityCriteria', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'RegistrationBundle:PriorityCriteria',
                'choice_label' => 'text',
                'mapped' => false,
//                'choice_label' => function ($priorityCriterias) {
//                    return $priorityCriterias->getText();
//                },
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->getCriteriaList();
                },

                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-success']]);
    }
```

Вообщем может я совсем кривую логику пытаюсь реализовать ?? Устал уже решать эту задачку не подается , может сможет кто подсказать чего )